# json - can't access an object in php

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I'm trying to loop through some json data but I'm having problems with accessing it:

```
 $request = wp_remote_get( 'https://api.riderhq.com/api/v1/3446/getevents?pretty=true' );

  if( is_wp_error( $request ) ) {
    echo "wrong request";
    return false; // Bail early
  }

  $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request );
  print_r($body); //prints stuff

  $data = json_decode($body);

  print_r($data['events']); // doesn't print anything
  print_r($data); // doesn't print enything
  print_r($data[0]); // doesn't print anything
```

The object contains one top-level element called 'events' and then under that the proper data is organised. Straight away I'd like to access $data->events but I'm having problem displaying anything.

Comment: As we found out the issue happens because of "Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded" error that could be found when http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php is used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set second parameter to **true** if you want to use decoded json as array

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

```
$data = json_decode($body, true);
```

Comment: Thanks, but after adding the second parameter, still neither of the last three command outputs anything

Comment: Can you post here output of print_r($body);

Comment: Also do print_r($data); after $data = json_decode($body); and post it here

Comment: print_r($data) does not output anyting

Comment: check if it's valid json using: function isJson($string) {
 json_decode($string);
 return (json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE);
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180303/discussion-between-evgpisarchik-and-wasteland).